# List Comprehension: Inserting x into the list if x is not in the list already?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

In Python 3, is there a way to do a list comprehension where some object, x, gets inserted into the list if it's not already in the same list. I basically want the code to do this:

```
my_list = ["aa", "aa", "bb", "bb"]
new_list = [c for c in my_list if c not in new_list]  ## Add each c from my_list into new_list if c is not already in new_list.
```

I don't want to delete duplicates in `my_list` and I strictly need a list comprehension technique. Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: This seems like a perfect use for `set()`. You _have_ to use a list comprehension?

Comment: @SeanBreckenridge Yes sir. I have to create a new list using list comprehension and I cannot use set().

Comment: It's possible, but in my opinion, best to just do a simple for loop to make this list. If order doesn't matter you can do something like `[item for item in set(some_list)]`

Comment: ... *why*? That seems like an absurd restriction.

Comment: @sytech is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes i understand, but that is what I've been told to do.

Comment: Been told by whom?

Comment: [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has a recipe for `unique_everseen`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga comp sci teacher. it's very frustrating.

Comment: @sytech do you mind providing more details on how to use that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sytech the `unique_everseen` recipe*uses a `set`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a horribly inefficient way to accomplish this:

```
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x not in my_list[:i]]
['aa', 'bb']
```

It's O(N^2) time and O(N) space.

Don't use this. Write *good code*.

A similarly inefficient solution:

```
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if my_list.index(x) == i]
['aa', 'bb']
```

Comment: Yes I very well know that this is not good code. However, my comp sci teacher does not seem to understand this. Sad! Thanks anyway.

Comment: and what would be the efficient solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways in one line without modifying origional list, Here are some ways :

using list comprehension :

```
my_list = ["aa", "aa", "bb", "bb"]
new_list=[]
[new_list.append(i) for i in my_list if i not in new_list]
```

using set:

```
my_list = ["aa", "aa", "bb", "bb"]
print(list(set(my_list)))
```

Using itertools:

```
import itertools
print(list(map(lambda x:x[0],itertools.groupby(my_list))))
```

using collections:

```
import collections
print(collections.Counter(my_list).keys())
```

using dict.fromkeys():

```
print(list(dict.fromkeys(my_list)))
```

Answer (score -1):

O(N) space and O(N) time by using an auxiliary set:

```
seen = set()
[seen.add(x) or x for x in my_list if x not in seen]
```

returns

```
['aa', 'bb']
```